# Installed Python, but can't get a hello world

Tags: python, apache

Total Python beginner here on CentOS.

I've installed Python per the instructions: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

Added the following to my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/financial">
AllowOverride None
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've got my hello world file in my root directory:

```
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 jeremy www   42 Jun  9 20:29 index.py
```

index.py looks like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import sys

 sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")

 print "Hello, World!"
```

I'm getting an internal server error when I try to load the page.

Unfortunately my system administration skills are about 2/10, so I'm pretty stuck at the moment.

Comment: Can you show the error log, properly `/var/log/httpd/error_log`?

Comment: @BSH [Mon Jun 09 21:12:11 2014] [error] [client 74.71.63.173] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/html/financial/index.py' failed
[Mon Jun 09 21:12:11 2014] [error] [client 74.71.63.173] Premature end of script headers: index.py

Comment: Double check where you installed your python, and make sure it is `/usr/bin/python`, use `which python` if you have a shell.

Comment: @BSH Well, I guess that's a good question.  I just used the defaults when I installed it. The which command gives me "/usr/bin/python", but there are two other entries in the /bin folder: python2 and python2.4...however, I'm quite sure that I installed python3.4

Comment: Appreciate your help, but i'm very close to scrapping it and starting over with a new server instance and an OS that I don't have to install from source on :)

Comment: Type `python -V` and see the version, if it's 3.X, you need to change `print "..."` to `print("...")`.

Comment: Python 2.4.3  Looks like I screwed up the install.   Definitely going to start from scratch tomorrow. Thanks, though.